# Datepicker "Done" button not showing up in Display Button Bar Panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, datepicker

I currently have my instance of Datepicker displaying the Button Bar panel that includes the "Today" button, but not the "Done" button. The code I've used to display the button bar is:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                    showButtonPanel: true
            });           

    });
    </script>
```

[image: This is how it displays]

I thought by default the "Done" button would show when the showButtonPanel is set to "true." Is there something more that I should add?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @scessor programmers (noobs) these days, don't have sense of humor...

Comment: @Grigor http://i.stack.imgur.com/jsa00.png

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v9rZc/

Comment: @j08691 Yes, it works fine on the jQuery UI demo page, which is why it's so perplexing. I haven't modified the code in the uijquery nor jquery, so I would expect it to function "out of the box."

The "Today" button shows up, so is there anything more to showButtonPanel: true to get the "Done" button to appear as well?

Thanks for prompt reply.

Comment: It's could be something with your CSS, or if you have other JavaScript on your page.

Comment: you probably don't have all the images/files that need to be included

Comment: @Grigor.. I am using the online jquery ui for css so I doubt that it is the problem. http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Comment: Do you have more datepicker options? And do you have some css rules for the classes _ui-datepicker-close_, _ui-state-default_, _ui-priority-primary_ or _ui-corner-all_?

Comment: @j08691 Actually I have the datepicker as visibility:hidden; first and it pop up when a button is clicked which changes to 'visibility','visible'

Comment: @scessor I do not have any other css rules other than visibility for the datepicker

Comment: It may be due to various reasons: using not the current version of jQuery and jQuery UI, css rules, other javascript or javascript errors... It would be much easier if you could give us a link to the page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The buttonPanel does not show the close button if you haven't added your datepicker to an input element

Make sure you are attaching your datepicker to an input and not something like a div.

Comment: I do not want to attach the Datepicker to a input field as I am capturing the returned date and piping it into a function rather than displaying the value on an input field. Is there a way around using an input field?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                    showButtonPanel: true
            }); 
            $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "showButtonPanel", true );


          });
```

if you still can't get, look for js error in firebug etc

Comment: Huh? Of course there's a done button on the datepicker, and there's obviously an answer since the default behavior is to have a done button if showButtonPanel if true.

Comment: @CoDe aDDict...Thanks, I will look into those documentation

Comment: @CoDeaDDict...I tried your sample code, still the same. I even updated to the latest jqueryUI. Its really tricky. Firebug does not even prompt for any js errors as all the scripts seems to be in order